# How can I forward a port through ssh that is available only to localhost?

Tags: networking, mac, port-forwarding

So I'm connecting to a computer through ssh, and it has a port open that I can only connect to using localhost. Is there any way I can forward that port to my local machine?

Setup:

```
My machine -> SSH server
```

As of now, I can only lynx `SSH sever:port`, but I'd like to be able to do `My machine:some port` and have all traffic be sent to `SSH server:port`. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work ?

ssh yourlogin@sshserver -L someport:127.0.0.1:serverport

With :

- someport = the port in 'Your Machine:some port'
- serverport = the port in 'server:port'

I didn't try it with 127.0.0.1, but usually with an IP visible only from the server I'm SSHing to. I'm interested to know if this is working (but don't known why it will not work)